# Как проверить в sqlite3, что при использовании оператора NOT IN список не пустой

Tags: sql, sqlite3

У меня есть часть кода, в которой я проверяю, что id события нет в другой таблице

```
(events.id NOT IN (SELECT id_event FROM watched_events WHERE id_user = ?)
```

Однако подзапрос `SELECT id_event FROM watched_events WHERE id_user = ?` может возвращать пустой список, и весь запрос будет возвращать None.

Вот как выглядит весь запрос

```
SELECT id, name, type, description, longitude, latitude, time,
  members_all, members_on_event
FROM events,users, watched_events
WHERE (users.id_user = ?) AND
  (events.id NOT IN (SELECT id_event FROM watched_events WHERE id_user = ?)) AND
  (6371000*2*asin(sqrt(pow(sin(rad((latitude-abs(user_latitude))/2)), 2) +
  cos(rad(latitude))*cos(rad(abs(user_latitude)))*
  pow(sin(rad((longitude-user_longitude)/2)), 2))) < ?)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить правильно, пустой ли лист.

Comment: Да вроде бы `NOT IN (пустой_список)` должно получаться `TRUE`, может у вас в другом месте проблема?

Comment: Да, при пустом листе получается TRUE, сейчас уточню вопрос. Я запускал программу с пустой таблицей watched_events и получал пустой массив, но если в watched_events была запись, то программа выдавала все записи из events правильно (т. е. те события, id которых не было в watched_events). Может я не совсем понял логику NOT INTO

Comment: WHERE NOT IN легко превращается в WHERE NOT EXISTS либо LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL.

Comment: Заменил NOT IN на LEFT JOIN. Всё стало работать корректно. Спасибо огрномное!